# Disallow merge of specific branches in GitLab-CI

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, rules

How to prevent branch merging in dev | stage | master if the branch name does not start with the corresponding prefix? 
The name of the branch should begin with the name where the code is added.
For example, for a merge request in master to be accepted, the branch should be called master / new_merge_config.

Help, please, how to create a similar rule? Or can you do without merge rules?

Answer (score 0):

my Bash scripting is not the best but you could create something like this:

```yaml
merging:
  stage: validation
  only: [merge_requests]
  script:
     - [[ "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^master$ ]] && [[ ! "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^master ]] && echo 'not allowed merge to master' &&  exit 1 || echo 'merge master ok'
     - [[ "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^stage$ ]] && [[ ! "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^stage ]] && echo 'not allowed merge to stage' &&  exit 1 || echo 'merge stage ok'
     - [[ "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^dev$ ]] && [[ ! "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" =~ ^dev ]] && echo 'not allowed merge to dev' &&  exit 1 || echo 'merge dev ok'
```

See [this list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) with available variables on gitlab-ci